# Mocking and unit test passes even though assertion is not correct

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, xunit.net, justmock

I'm very new to unit testing and TDD on a whole.

I have the following Login method in my Service layer (WCF) which is hosted as a windows service. My service layer follows the facade pattern, and all calls to the service layer are made with requests objects and returns the corresponding response object.

```
public LoginResponse Login(LoginRequest request)
{
    var response = new LoginResponse(request.RequestId);
    try
    {
        if (!ValidRequest(request, response, Validate.ClientTag))
            return response;

        var user = userDao.GetByUserId(request.UserId);
        if (user != null)
        {                   
            if (request.Password != "")
            {
                var authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();
                if (authenticationService.Authenticate(user, request.Password))
                {                          
                    return response;
                }                        
                response.ErrorCode = "IncorrectPassword";
            }
            else
            {                       
                response.ErrorCode = "PasswordNotFound";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            response.ErrorCode = "UserNotFound";
        }
        response.Acknowledge = AcknowledgeType.Failure;
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex);
        response.Acknowledge = AcknowledgeType.Failure;
        response.ErrorCode = "Exception";
        return response;
    }
}
```

Both lines here:

```
userDao.GetByUserId(request.UserId);
```

and

```
authenticationService.Authenticate(user, request.Password);
```

are making calls to the DB.

Here's the test I've written with xUnit and JustMock:

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("manager", "manager")]
    public void LoginTest(string userId, string password)
    {
        //Arrange
        var userServiceMock = Mock.Create<IUserManagementService>();

        var request = new LoginRequest().Prepare();
        request.UserId = userId;
        request.Password = password;

        var response = new LoginResponse(request.RequestId);

        Mock.Arrange(() => userServiceMock.Login(request)).Returns(response).OccursOnce();

        //Act
        userServiceMock.Login(request);

        //Assert
        Mock.Assert(userServiceMock);            
    }
```

The problem I'm having is even after I've changed my service method to

```
public LoginResponse Login(LoginRequest request)
{
    return null;
}
```

My test still passes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not testing anything. What do you wish to test?

Comment: For starters, I would like to test that my Login method returns LoginResponse. And then maybe test if I pass in am empty username, my test should fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not testing anything. You are mocking your system under test which is not correct.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17568557/1228889) for a brief explanation of what a mock is.

If you are testing `UserManagementService.Login()` you'd want:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("manager", "manager")]
public void LoginTest(string userId, string password)
{
    // Arrange
    // System under test
    IUserManagementService userService = new UserManagementService();

    var request = new LoginRequest().Prepare();
    request.UserId = userId;
    request.Password = password;

    var expectedResponse = new LoginResponse(request.RequestId);

    //Act
    var actualResponse = userService.Login(request);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(actualResponse.Something, expectedResponse.Something);            
}
```

No need to mock anything. (You may need to mock any dependencies that `Login()` has such as `AuthenticationService`, `userDao` and even `Log` if you don't want your unit test to write to the log.)

Comment: +1 Our posts were just 7 seconds apart and yet we're both saying pretty much the same :-)

Comment: Great minds think alike. + 1 Although, I did comment ~ 5 minutes before either of our answers. :)

Comment: Good point. You won the race anyway. Your answer was the 7s earlier one according to SO :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have mocked the class that you want to test. When you call `Login` on the `userServiceMock`, the following line of code is relevant:

```
Mock.Arrange(() => userServiceMock.Login(request)).Returns(response).OccursOnce();
```

That is, you always return a valid result. The actual code is never executed.

Each of your unit tests will have a "system under test" (SUT). You will never want to mock the SUT itself. You only mock any other objects that your SUT depends on. In your case, the `UserService` seems to be your SUT. There is no reason to mock the user service, you want to test the real one!

However the SUT seems to use a `UserDao` which is probably injected somewhere. Inject a mock of the UserDAO instead of a real one.

Furthermore it uses a `AuthenticationService`. Unfortunately it is not injected but your method creates an instance on the fly. This makes it impossible to use a mock implementation of it. You will need to refactor your UserService such that you can inject the `AuthenticationService` to be used. Then your unit test can inject a mock of the `AuthenticationService`.